# C++ Pointer address assignment of the kind: x = (x->next new node(i,t)) prints different results than what I am expecting

Tags: c++, pointers, variable-assignment

I do not understand how assignment is happening in this code for the line:

```
x = (x->next = new myNode(i, t));
```

Can you help me understand this? Sorry, if I am asking a basic question.
 I am just trying to learn pointer assignments clearly.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
struct myNode {
  int res;
  myNode *next;
  // constructor
  myNode(int value, myNode* nextRes) {
   res = value;
   next  = nextRes;
 }
}; 

typedef myNode *nodePtr;

int main() {
 int i;
 int N = 9;
 int M = 3;
 cout << "ISSUED N:" << N << endl;
 cout << "ISSUED M:" << M << endl;
 nodePtr t = new myNode(1,0);
 t->next = t;
 nodePtr x = t;
 cout << "Address of t:" << t << endl;
 cout << "Address of t->next:" << t->next << endl;
 cout << "Address of x:" << x << endl;
 cout << "Address of x->next:" << x->next << endl;
 for (i = 2; i <= N; i++) {
  x = (x->next = new myNode(i, t));

  cout << "i = " << i <<endl;
  cout << "t is:" << t << endl;
  cout << "x is:" << x << endl;
  cout << "x->next is:" << x->next << endl;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

When I compile it and run it, I get the following result:

```
linux% g++ -o main.exe *.cpp
linux% main.exe
ISSUED N:9
ISSUED M:3
Address of t:0x19e5c30
Address of t->next:0x19e5c30
Address of x:0x19e5c30
Address of x->next:0x19e5c30
i = 2
t is:0x19e5c30
x is:0x19e5c50
x->next is:0x19e5c30
i = 3
t is:0x19e5c30
x is:0x19e5c70
x->next is:0x19e5c30
i = 4
t is:0x19e5c30
x is:0x19e5c90
x->next is:0x19e5c30
i = 5
...
...
so on
```

The above result is different than what I was expecting.

From this line of code:

```
x = (x->next = new myNode(i, t));
```

I was expecting that the result of:

```
new myNode(i,t)
```

will be assigned to:

```
x->next
```

first and then that value of

```
x->next
```

is assigned to

```
x.
```

In that case, for i = 2, below is what I see in the result I posted above:

```
t is:0x19e5c30
x is:0x19e5c50
x->next is:0x19e5c30
```

I was expecting:

```
x
```

and

```
x->next,
```

will have the same value, which is:

```
0x19e5c50.
```

But I see that the value of

```
x->next
```

is the same as

```
t
```

and

```
x
```

has a different address value.

Can someone explain why this is so?

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand the bug I inadvertently introduced!

I should have written the for loop part of the code like this:

```
for (i = 2; i <= N; i++) {
  cout << "i = " << i <<endl;
  cout << "t is:" << t << endl;
  //x = (x->next = new myNode(i, t));

  x->next = new myNode(i, t);
  cout << "x->next is:" << x->next << endl;

  x = x->next;
  cout << "x is:" << x << endl;    

 }
```

That above correction produces the right answers.

Comment: This is not an answer.  You should update your question with this info and delete this answer.  Why you got upvotes for this is beyond me.

Comment: It's good to hear that you found the cause of your problem.  You could make your answer more helpful for future readers by explaining *how* you diagnosed it, and in particular, which evidence will identify this problem when it's seen elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = (x->next = new myNode(i, t));
```

That's the same as :

```
x->next = new myNode(i, t);
x = x->next;
```

First, you change `x->next` to point to a new `myNode` which has `t` in it's `next` member.

Then, you assign that `myNode` to `x`.

So `x` is now pointing to that new `myNode` which has `t` in it's `next` member.

Hence, `x->next == t`.